# Convert PDFs to Google docs and get extracted text along with link to original PDF file into a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm just facing a little problem in getting the link to the PDF file when I run a script to convert PDF files to Google docs with OCR then populate the results into a google sheets.

So far I get the name of the file created (Google Docs) and the extracted text.

what I'm trying to achieve: on the 3rd column, I'd like to get the link of the PDF file corresponding to the Google docs created

I've tried to include the variable pdf to the push array:

```
    var pdf = document.getId();
...
    output.push([name, body, pdf]);
```

but I get the same ID for all files. Ideally I'd like to get the full link to the PDF file and not only it's ID, to avoid having to create a column with:

```
=CONCATENATE("https://drive.google.com/file/d/",C2)
```

where C2 contains the ID of the PDF file.

Here is the code:

```
function extractTextOnOpen() {



var folderName = "OCR TESTS";

   var sheetId = "SHEET'S ID HERE";

  //Define Project folder

var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
var folderId = folder.getId();

//Find all PDFs in folder

var documents = folder.getFilesByType("application/pdf");
while (documents.hasNext()) {

    //Convert each PDF to a Google Doc with OCR
    var document = documents.next();

    // Get the PDF link to insert in the sheet for reference

    var pdf = document.getId();


    var imageName = document.getName();
    var docName = imageName.split("\.")[0];
    var file = {
        title: docName,
        mimeType: "application/pdf"
        // for images, use: "image/png"

    }
    Drive.Files.insert(file, document, { ocr: true });

    //Store newly-created Google Doc in the same project folder

    var newFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(docName).next();
    folder.addFile(newFile);
    var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    rootFolder.removeFile(newFile);
}

//Find all Google Docs in the project folder

var docs = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");

//Set up spreadsheet

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
Logger.log('File name: ' + ss.getName());


  // specify the sheet to insert the results

 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');


// Set up the spreadsheet to display the results

 var headers = [["File Name", "Test Paper Scanned", "PDF Link"]];
  sheet.getRange("A1:C").clear()
  sheet.getRange("A1:C1").setValues(headers);


 var output = [];

//Populate spreadsheet with OCR text

while (docs.hasNext()) {
    var file = docs.next();
    var docId = file.getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
    var name = doc.getName();
    var body = doc.getBody().getText();

       output.push([name, body, pdf]);

   // write data to the sheet

  sheet.getRange(2, 1, output.length, 3).setValues(output);

}};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unnecessary loop and so you're losing your opportunity to save the PDF URLs. I've changed the order of your code to show you how this works. Essentially, all of the work happens within the first loop where you iterate through the PDFs.*

```
function extractTextOnOpen() {
  var folderName = "OCR TESTS";
  var sheetId = "SHEET'S ID HERE";

  //Set up spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);

  // specify the sheet to insert the results  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Set up the spreadsheet to display the results
  var headers = ["File Name", "Test Paper Scanned", "PDF Link"];
  sheet.getRange("A1:C").clear()
  var output = [headers];

  //Define Project folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
  var folderId = folder.getId();

  //Find all PDFs in folder
  var pdfs = folder.getFilesByType("application/pdf");
  while (pdfs.hasNext()) {
    //Convert each PDF to a Google Doc with OCR
    var pdf = pdfs.next();    
    var imageName = pdf.getName();
    var docName = imageName.split("\.")[0];
    var file = {
      title: docName,
      mimeType: "application/pdf"
    };
    var driveFile = Drive.Files.insert(file, pdf, { ocr: true });

    //Store newly-created Google Doc in the same project folder
    var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(driveFile.id);
    folder.addFile(newFile);
    var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    rootFolder.removeFile(newFile);

    //Get the Google Doc data
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(driveFile.id);
    var name = doc.getName();
    var body = doc.getBody().getText();
    output.push([name, body, pdf.getUrl()]);
  }
  //Print to the sheet
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

In the code above, note that the Drive API returns a [file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files#resource), so that's used in the proceeding `.getFileById()` calls. You can then use either [`.getUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geturl) or [`.getDownloadUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getDownloadUrl()).

```
var driveFile = Drive.Files.insert(file, pdf, { ocr: true });

//Store newly-created Google Doc in the same project folder
var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(driveFile.id);
```

Also, you're using the batch `.setValues()`, which is faster, but you have it in a loop. I updated the script to print to the sheet only once at the very end.

* *If you really wanted to go through two loops of PDFs and then Google Docs, then you'd need to map the PDF IDs to the Google Doc IDs in that first loop.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, works fine with a little change, because I get an error (Cannot find function appendRow in object Range) with `sheet.getRange("A1:C").clear().appendRow(headers)` so I've put it back to what it was?? also The reason I've used `.setValues` is because the sheet has formulae starting from D2, and therefore I needed to have the results of the conversion right at the top, unless there is a better way of doing it? Could you please update the code regarding the error so it may be useful for anyone coming across a similar task, once again thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nabnub Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the code and made a slight modification to how printing to sheet was happening.

Comment: Thanks to you. I have accepted your answer. I'm trying to take this little project step by step. I'm trying at the moment with only 5 PDFs, and the time of execution is around 47 seconds. I'm starting to be worried a bit, when I'll have about 25 PDF files in the folder, **am I going to reach the 6 min execution limit with this method?** Maybe I'll have to post another question.

Comment: @Nabnub You might! Some of the calls you're making are slow and there's not much you can do to get around them. Going step-by-step is the right approach. If you do have another question, do post and someone will help you out :)

Comment: Hello @diego, It is very helpful. But considering that there is a unique ID for each PDF, how to avoid to convert every time all the PDFs but only the new ones?
(Considering for example that the folder could increase every day with new PDFs and so not processing the older).

Comment: @Gavis You should post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

### What about the method [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getUrl())?

Sample:

`var pdf = document.getUrl();`