# Following code to work for JPEG, instead of PDF when importing into google sheet from drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have managed to steal some code from the following answered question, which works flawlessly. However, I was wondering if someone knows how to edit it so it locates jpegs instead of pdfs. Had a go but I'm clearly missing something.

Thanks!

[Convert PDFs to Google docs and get extracted text along with link to original PDF file into a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245461/convert-pdfs-to-google-docs-and-get-extracted-text-along-with-link-to-original-p/59247008#59247008)

Comment: Have a read through the code, change pdf for jpeg, application/pdf for image/jpeg. If you could show what you've tried it is easier to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.